# Excel move row down in conditional statement

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to do the following in Excel: 
[image]
The easiest way is of course to just drag and drop, but as I have many rows and columns, this is not feasible.
I was thus thinking that the following should work:

```
=IF(B6="Food", "Food", "insert two blank cells")
```

However, to my surprise, I was unable to find seomthing which would allow me to actually use "insert shift cells down" in a formula. What do I overlook, do I need to get started with VBA here?

Thanks!

Comment: I only need "after", i.e. the stuff below "After" would replace "Before", in a new sheet for instance. What I did in the picture above is to drag and drop F6:7 to F8:9.

Comment: Formulae cannot, among other things, add rows, so yes you will have to delve into VBA. Have a go and post your code if you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the following code would do what you expect:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your Sheet above
lastrow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'find the last row with data on Column A

For i = 6 To lastrow 'loop from row 6 to last
    If ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = "Food" Then 'if Food is found
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'insert a blank cell on Column B
        ws.Cells(i, 2).Insert Shift:=xlDown 'again insert a second blank cell on Column B
    End If
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, @Xabier, this is great for getting started with VBA! Your code works for the example I posted, however, my example had a shortcoming. I did not include more columns which would illustrate that Row 6 could read "Food"- "Drink" - "Food"- "Food" - "Drink", and that the condition I need is not existence of "Food", but "Drink" ONLY if the cell left to it is "Food" . Thus, I need to learn how to have two conditions. Another thing I wonder is how to write the code so that the code runs over all of my 500 columns and not just the first one which seems to happen at this point. Anyways, thanks!

Comment: If you have any issues getting that done, post another question and I will do my best to reply to it.. For the time being would you mark my response as an answer if it has helped you? Thanks.